# Spyder shows two editors

Tags: python, spyder, pane

While writing code in Spyder, I have accidentally pressed a control which caused Spyder to show to editors next to each other. What can I do to close one editor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

alt+shift+W should work, can you please try it?

Comment: make sure that you are on one of the editor windows first

Comment: This worked for me! What command does this execute? I couldn't find a reference to alt+shit+w in Spyder.

Comment: @foggy here https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/editor.html#split-panels it's to close the current pane